# How validate a textarea that required minimum white space?

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli

Needs to validate a form, in that text area and input fields, if anyone typed without whitespaces and fully in capital letters. I need to validate minimum white space required and dont type fully in capital letters...

Answer (score 1):

First off you should be able to use trim() in PHP for the whitespace issue.

To check for only captial letters you can use this, very simple way of doing it

```
strtoupper($str) == $str
```

Comment: And `http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php` if he want to find whitespace

Comment: He sloud use `mb_strtoupper`, as this will fail with unicode letters, for example `ŠŤÁVA`.

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to catch this on the client, before submitting (where you will also check), you can use match to count instances of a pattern in a string.

```
function validSpacesNoShouting(input){
    var  s= input.value, L= input.value.length,
    minspace= 1+ L/10, //figure min spacing
    lowC= (s.match(/([a-z])/g) || []).length,
    upC= (s.match(/([A-Z])/g) || []).length;
    return s.match(/(\s)/g).length> minspace && lowC> upC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

js
avoid
 White space,

- trim();
- replace();

Avoide Caps or Small letter

- toUpperCase( );
- toLowerCase( );